# Custom Product Type -- Hidden Custom Option or Data Field

Tags: magento

I'm building a custom Magento product type class. When the user adds an item of this product type to their cart, certain data needs to be associated with the item. A custom option would work well for storing this data except for the fact that the info needs to be kept hidden from the user.

I'm thinking that I either need to create some kind of hidden custom option or somehow add another datafield to the product. How would you suggest that I do this?

Thank you,
Ben

Comment: I know this question is answered, however, I am interested in your application. Can you please provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: This was for an item with such complex options that Magento's standard custom options functionally was insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom product's model add a function like this:

```
public function prepareForCart(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product = null)
{
    $buyRequest->setCertainData(...);
    return parent::prepareForCart($buyRequest, $product);
}
```

This will store the 'certain data' as the result of a custom option without the effort of creating an option. Once ordered it will be carried over to the order's item's "product options" where you can later [retrieve it](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item.html#getProductOptionByCode) with:

```
// $item is a Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item
$item->getProductOptionByCode('certain_data');
```

Comment: Hum...Magento didn't seem to call the prepareForCart method.

Comment: That is unusual. I've successfully used it to store extra product data and some of Magento's existing product types also have that function.

Comment: I'd like to dig more into this when I have time with the hopes of finding out why my code's prepareForCart wasn't called.

Comment: this does not work, at all, prepareForCart is a method of an option model, not the product model itself.

Comment: @sucitivel; it's true `prepareForCart()` is a method of [product options](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Default.html#prepareForCart), but it is also a method of [product types](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract.html#prepareForCart).

Comment: either way, it doesn't work.  overloading this does: protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)